# Pass in long parameter to asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to pass a website parameter to a webapi, but it fails to work.

Webapiconfig:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

Web api controller: take the param and return the htmlsnapshot of the other website

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/snapshot/{param}")]
    public string GetSnapShot(string param)
    {

        string fragment = param;
        string content = "";

        if (fragment != null)
        {
            int firstSlash = fragment.IndexOf("/");
            if (firstSlash <= 2)
                fragment = fragment.Substring(firstSlash + 1, fragment.Length - firstSlash - 1);
            using (IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
            {
                string url = String.Format("http://domain.com/{0}", fragment);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

                content = driver.PageSource;
            }
        }
        return content;
    }
```

if I try api/snapshot/du-lieu  -> hit the controller fine but if I pass in a more complicated like

api/snapshot/%2Fdu-lieu%2Fbong-da-y-Serie-A%2Fseason%2F1%2Ftong-quan -> fails to work, return 404

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you put your param into query string??
Your code will become

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/snapshot")]
public string GetSnapShot(string param1,string param2,string param3)
{
}
```

And from wherever you call the api, create the request url
`http://<whatever domain you use>/api/snapshot?param1=valueparam1&param2=valueparam2&param3=valueparam3`

Comment: No, i only want it a unique param as  other site will pass in a dynamic params, my webapi returns the htmlsnapshot. I've updated my code in full above.

Comment: is there any error message or something that define "not working" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/snapshot/{*param}")]
        public string GetSnapShot(string param)
{

}
```

It works now, thanks all.